# Stochastic coordinate descent for $\ell_1$ regularization

Tags: regression, lasso, regularization

I recently came across the following paper:  "[Stochastic Methods for $\ell_1$ Regularized Loss Minimization](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~shais/papers/ShalevTewari09.pdf)" by Shai Shalev-Shwartz and Ambuj Tewari, ICML 2009.

In the paper, the authors propose a modification of the coordinate descent algorithm for the LASSO in which the coordinates (the $\beta$s) are updated in a random order. This modification appears to have better run-time performance than deterministic coordinate descent.

Can you offer any intuition for why such a modification would make the algorithm faster in practice?

Comment: I would guess it might be related to the problems that steepest descent has that the conjugate gradient method corrects.

Comment: I wonder why the optimization problem (5) in the paper is equivalent to the original problem? How to verify that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that in the specific case of L2 loss (ordinary linear regression), the convergence rate of coordinate descent will depend on the correlation structure of the predictors ($X_i$’s).  Consider the case where they are uncorrelated.  Then cyclic coordinate descent converges after one cycle.

Another heuristic that has had more empirical evidence in its favor is the idea of active set convergence.  Rather than cycling through all coordinates, only cycle through the ones that are active ($i$’s where $\beta_i$ is non-zero) until convergence, then sweep through the all coordinates to update the active set.  Convergence occurs when the active set does not change.